# Knitr markdown can't display basic symbols

Tags: knitr, rstudio

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, running RStudio Version 0.99.473. I have LaTeX installed (TeXworks) and knitting Rmarkdown documents works just fine. However, adding mathematical symbols such as `$\mu$` causes it to fail, with the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.128 N(\(\mu, \simga

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

(in my .Rmd file, I have $\mu, \sigma^2$ - it works if I remove the $'s and the slashes)

In my experience, the LaTeX package `amssymb` has a lot of math symbols. `tlmgr install amssymb` doesn't work, so I'm lost.

```
tlmgr install amssymb
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012 
     (2011--2012)
do not include the version of the local installation 
     (2013).
```

(I don't actually know what that error means. Can it find some files but not the right ones? Do I need a different repository? How do I find different repositories?)

How do I get `$\mu$` to show up? I'm going to need to have more complicated equations, so it would be really nice to get basic math working.

I should also mention that I have no idea where/how RStudio looks for LaTeX packages. I'm a Linux noob, but it's my only OS right now. Sorry if this isn't relevant to this forum, but this seemed like the right place to post it.

Comment: The macro `\simga` is undefined. Try with `\sigma`...

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get anywhere without the `amssymb` and `amsmath` packages. It looks as if you're running TeX Live 2013; updating to 2015 will make you much happier.

Knitr uses Pandoc to convert Markdown to LaTeX. Creating a file containing `$\mu, \sigma^2$` works fine with Pandoc 1.15.1.1 and TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to do that. What do you mean "create a file"? What extension? Where do I put it? What actually goes in the file? How do I update TeX Live? (I tried `tlmgr update -self' and `sudo apt-get update texworks`, but neither did anything. I also tried reinstalling both TeXLive and TeXWorks from Ubuntu Software Center.) I'm really not that knowledgeable here, I just want some basic math symbols :(

Comment: The TeX Live manager can only update within a single year; you need to download the complete 2015 distribution as appropriate for your system.